# How to sum a set of columns grouped by one column

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I have a dataframe like so

```
ID <- c('John', 'Bill', 'Alice','Paulina')
Type1 <- c(1,1,0,1)
Type2 <- c(0,1,1,0)     
cluster <- c(1,2,3,1)

test <- data.frame(ID, Type1, Type2, cluster)
```

I want to group by cluster and sum the values in all the other columns apart from ID that should be dropped.

I achieved it through

```
test.sum <- test %>%
  group_by(cluster)%>%
  summarise(sum(Type1), sum(Type2))
```

However, I have thousands of types and I can't write out each column in summarise manually. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where`across()` and `contains` comes in incredibly useful to select the columns you want to summarise across:

```
test %>% 
    group_by(cluster) %>% 
    summarise(across(contains("Type"), sum))
```

```
  cluster Type1 Type2
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     2     0
2       2     1     1
3       3     0     1
```

Alternatively, pivoting the dataset into long and then back into wide means you can easily analyse all groups and clusters at once:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c(ID, cluster)) %>% 
    group_by(cluster, name) %>% 
    summarise(sum_value = sum(value)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "sum_value")
```

```
  cluster Type1 Type2
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     2     0
2       2     1     1
3       3     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks the second option worked. The first isn't suitable as my actual data has different names not just 'Type1', 'Type2' that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @YuryMoskaltsov there's a bunch of very useful other functions for selecting columns which could be useful [found here](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html). It would probably be preferable to use those, as pivoting the table twice could be costly if you have a big dataset (or not, if it's small).

Answer (score 0):

**Base R**

You can exploit `split` which is equivalent to `group_by()`. This should give you what you are looking for, regardless of how many `Type`s you have.

```
my_split <- split(subset(test, select = grep('^Ty', names(test))), test[, -1]$cluster)
my_sums <- sapply(my_split, \(x) colSums(x))
my_sums <- data.frame( cluster = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", '', colnames(my_sums))),
                       t(my_sums) )
```

**Output**

```
> my_sums
  cluster Type1 Type2
1       1     2     0
2       2     1     1
3       3     0     1
```

Note: use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)` if you use a version of R <4.1.0